# NGINX reverse proxy not decrypting traffic to python flask app

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, flask, amazon-ec2, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am using an amazon EC2 server and have an issue with my NGINX reverse proxy. The domain  When running the  flask app on HTTP, I observe the expected behavior. However, when I switch to HTTPS

Error log from flask: [22/Sep/2023 17:55:44] code 400, message Bad request version ('\x00\x02\x01\x00\x00\x1b\x00\x03\x02\x00\x02\x00\x17\x00\x00\x00')

My NGINX is configured like this:

HTTPS server block:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name [domainname].com www.[domainname].com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/[domainname].com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/[domainname].com/privkey.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:7899/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    # Specific location block for the chatbot path
    location /chatbot {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:7899/chatbot/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    }
}
```

The flask app is setup to receive HTTP traffic

Flask app

```
 from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from langchain import PromptTemplate, LLMChain
from langchain.llms import OpenAI
from flask_cors import CORS
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

os.environ['OPENAI_API_KEY']  = [API key]

davinci = OpenAI(model_name='text-davinci-003')
template_str = “””[PROMPT]”””

prompt = PromptTemplate(template=template_str, input_variables=['question'])

llm_chain = LLMChain(
    prompt=prompt,
    llm=davinci
)

@app.route('/chatbot', methods=['POST'])
def chatbot_response():
    data = request.json
    if not data or 'question' not in data:
        return jsonify({"error": "Invalid request format. 'question' key is required."}), 400
    question = data['question']
    response = llm_chain.run(question)
    return jsonify({"response": response})

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def response():
    return jsonify({"response": "hi"})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=7899)
```

Please note that I redacted the port + domain name and API keys. Thus, it shouldnt be an issue with those. I'm new to backend and dont want to expose myself to malicious attacks.

Thank you so much!

I have tried the app with HTTP traffic and it does work, just when we switch to HTTPS it no longer works. I think, that this is not working because it seems the flask server is getting encrypted traffic.